# mat-sidenav push property causing a build error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I'm on Angular 6 and am using mat-sidenav

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer position="end" fixedInViewport="true" [mode]="push" [opened]="false">
```

However, when I run ng build --prod, it throws an error Property 'push' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'.

Everythign works fine, but this error is hindering our deployment process.

Also, another question. Why is [mode] in square brackets. Aren't square brackets in Angular 2+ used only when evaluating an expression? In this case it's just the string 'push' right? If I remove the square brackets, the sidenav stops working.

Comment: exactly, remove [] from mode. simple use mode="push" is actual value `push` assign to mode, while `[mode]="push"` here push is class variable not a actula value. like property binding. so simple try removing `[]` and use `mode="push"`

Comment: Actually yeah you're right. mode="over" works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `push` is the actual literal value that is expected in the `mat-sidenav` component, then pass the string push within single quotes.

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer position="end" fixedInViewport="true" [mode]="'push'" [opened]="false">
```

If you don't pass in the single quotes, the angular code will search for a variable in your component named push and pass its value to `mat-sidenav`